# Have I reached borders of CSS? Button to work on all devices

Tags: html, css

I am redesigning site to make it accessible on all devices. Main element is list of buttons that does fairly easy animation, but can not get it responsive. Please help.

Buttons live can be seen [here](http://atkusn.is/) (to disable video click in top right corner)

Details:
1.Title need to stay rigid, so it does not move along borders (to do so, previously used position:absolute;)
2.on hover border expand inwards + narrows by lets say 10px on left and right sides.
3. Title position on left side, arrow on right.
4. Text on smaller screens should break and border to be fluid.

Result so far:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvmWgM

Text breaks fine and borders goes along it, arrow is positioned on right. Cool. Except text moves on hover and borders expands outwards. Arrow is not vertically aligned.

Any bright ideas how to adjust buttons so they act as example on live site?

Thanks in advance,

```
.container {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.floatleft {
  float:left;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.floatright {float:right;}
.clear {clear:both;}

.button-wrap {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width:4px;
  display:block;      
  padding:30px 20px;
  transition: all .12s ease;
}
.button-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
a.project-title {
  color:#000;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400; 
  transition: all .4s ease;
  display: block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.button-wrap:hover {
  outline-width:6px;
  margin:0 20px;

}
.button-wrap:hover a.project-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: all .12s ease;
}
.arrow {
transition: all .4s ease;
margin-top: -4px;
  margin-right:20px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.button-wrap:hover  .arrow {
margin-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw something together for you: http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/pen/YyNdQe.

I started from scratch so you will have to adapt the things you can use. In order to avoid shenanigans with text reflowing I used

```
box-shadow
```

and

```
 text-shadow
```

It seems to confirm to your four rules.

Comment: Neat try! Clever use of text-shadow! But text will keep moving if on hover button shrinks horizontally.

Comment: When will the button shrink horizontally on hover? All the dimensions of all the divs remain the same on hover, only the box-shadow and text-shadow change on hover.

Comment: Yes on hover buttons supposed to shrink by 10px on both sides. I have no other idea than using position absolute to get text rigid. Ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. Why does the button itself have to shrink and not just its appearance?

Comment: see www.atkusn.is 
disable video and enjoy experience. it's just better to impress. even if its subjective...

Comment: I fail to see the big difference, both our buttons appear to shrink. In fact, because his button _does_ shrink you can bounce between the hovered state and the normal state if you hover over the left border. That is something that should be avoided imho.

Comment: Difference is that right now top and bottom of button shrinks same as left and right sides. On live dekstop version button shrink only on sides while top and bottom stays same height as in default state. Since border expands inwards, it seems that it also shrinks vertically too, but it doesnt. 

To sum up, yes, it is not possible with css due to lack of use of position absolute. Or am I wrong?

Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Ah, but that's not a problem. Take a look at [version 2](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/pen/bVgzyq).

Comment: way to go ! i only have question: why does buttons stop being fluid once screen width is less than 1000px ?

Comment: I think you're looking at a codepen artefact. Try it in [full screen mode](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/full/bVgzyq/).

Comment: Cheers. You solved the case! Thanks in advance. Ok, only arrow position on safari are wrong, but I'll try to get it on my own.. I appreciate ur time.